# Modelling class specific attributes in OO design

Tags: class, oop, object

What's the best approach to model a class specific attribute in object oriented design?

For example, a design for elements drawn on a canvas can modeled as follows:

```
                                 Shape
                                   |
                                   |
                            +-------------+
                            |             |
                            |             |
                          Circle       Square
```

We need to specify default background colors for `Circle` and `Square`. One way is to define them as `static` attributes.

Is there an object pattern for modelling such relationships?

EDIT: How would it such a pattern be modeled when the default backgrounds are changing rather frequently by a containing object such as `Canvas` ? (Canvas holds multiple instances of Shapes) 
Modeling an abstract class on base class would require me to update every instance of `Circle` and `Square`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a ShapeInfo class.  Each instance would refer to a Shape subclass and provide the background color for that class.  Statics are easier and probably the way to go, but this would give you the ability to have several groups of Circle instances with different backgrounds.  Also, you can extend the ShapeInfo class to provide better subclasses for Circle and Square.

If Circle and Square become highly complex classes, and are joined by many others, and if you have a lot of code that wants to treat them all as just Shape instances, this technique can become rather useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `abstract` method `getDefaultBackgroundColor()` to `Shape` and override it in each of the subclasses to return the appropriate color. With that, you will be able to determine the default background color of an arbitrary `Shape` instance, something you could not do using the `static` approach you mentioned.

Comment: Beat me by 28 seconds - essentially the same answer

Comment: This approach would result in redundant instances of default `Color` objects in every instance of `Circle` and `Square`. Is there a way to optimize that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `getDefaultColor()` in Shape, and override it in Circle and Square to return their specific default colors. No need for static methods there.

In other cases, it would be a useful feature: say you want to return, instead of a simple color, a default image. In that case, you would implement something like

Shape.java:

```
public abstract Image getDefaultImage();
```

Circle.java (extends Shape):

```
private static Image staticCircleImage = null;
public Image getDefaultImage() { 
   if (staticCircleImage == null) staticCircleImage = createStaticCircleImage();
   return staticCircleImage; 
}
```

Square.jave (extends Shape):

```
// same as above, but with staticSquareImage instead...
```

Since Java lacks static method overriding (or the concept of metaclasses), this is the way that it is usually implemented when needed.

Comment: This approach would result in redundant instances of default Color objects in every instance of Circle and Square. Is there a way to optimize that ?

Comment: Use the second option - that way the color is statically held in the classes, but the methods still provide the overriding that you want. Colors are relatively cheap, that is why I did not advocate it directly.